# Fluent Api - M:M relationship with two 1:M properties. How?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

I have this model. An athlete have multiple workouts, and multiple training plans. A workout can be in many training plans. A workout can be performed many times in a day this is why I need the extra field DateToPerform in the M:M relationship. How can I accomplish it, this is my model:

```
public class Athlete
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual List<Workout> Workouts {get; set;}
    public virtual List<TrainingPlan> TrainingPlans {get; set;}
}

public class Workout
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual Athlete Athlete {get; set;}  //Athlete owner of the WO.
    public virtual List<TrainingPlan> TrainingPlans {get; set;} //Plans where WO is.
}

public class TrainingPlan
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual Athlete Athlete {get; set;}  //Athlete owner of this TP.
    public virtual List<Workout> Workouts {get; set;} //Workouts in this plan.
}
```

Since I need the extra field, I read in SO that I should promote to Entity the relationship this is how I ended doing this:

```
public class TrainingPlanWorkout
{
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public virtual TrainingPlan TrainingPlan { get; set; }
        public virtual Workout Workout { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateToPerform { get; set; }
}
```

Now using the fluen´t API I define all these like this:

```
//I define primary keys.
modelBuilder.Entity<Athlete>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<TrainingPlan>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<Workout>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<TrainingPlanWorkout>().HasKey(x => x.Id);

modelBuilder.Entity<Athlete>().HasMany(a => a.AthleteTrainingPlans)
                              .WithRequired(t=>t.Athlete)
                              .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

modelBuilder.Entity<Athlete>().HasMany(m => m.AthleteWorkouts)
                              .WithRequired(m=>m.Athlete)
                              .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);


 modelBuilder.Entity<TrainingPlanWorkout>().HasRequired(t => t.TrainingPlan);
 modelBuilder.Entity<TrainingPlanWorkout>().HasRequired(t => t.Workout);
```

When I run the app I receive the following error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.TrainingPlanWorkouts_dbo.Workouts_Workout_Id' on table
>   'TrainingPlanWorkouts' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.
>   Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other
>   FOREIGN KEY constraints.

I think I'm overcomplicating things, what is the best way to accomplish this scenario?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the entity-framework nor anything else than C#. But why does a workout has to know, which athlete is using it? Can workouts be done without a training plan, or are they always part of a training plan? I'd try to get rid of some references if possible. This should then remove some foreign key constraints and maybe solve the problem.

Comment: The portal will have many athletes, in consequence many workouts, I need to know the owners since the athletes creates their workouts. The workouts are included in Training Plans.

Comment: Is a workout/training plan shared among athletes?

Comment: if answer of @Onur question is no, then it might just a simple one to many relationship

Comment: The answer is no. But I don't get what changes

Comment: A Workout can be in many training plans, a user is owner of many workouts and many training plans. He can put the same workout many times in one training plan and many times in many training plans. M:M in workout:trainigplans perspective. That is the M:M that I want to model I know how to do it but if you read the scenario I need extra fields, that is why I promoted another entity to have them, this is where the issue begins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented your problem using the following code, the main difference is in the modelBuilder for the relation entity.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Athlete
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

            private ICollection<Workout> workouts;
            public virtual ICollection<Workout> Workouts
            {
                get { return workouts ?? (workouts = new HashSet<Workout>()); }
                set { workouts = value; }
            }

            private ICollection<TrainingPlan> trainingPlans;
            public virtual ICollection<TrainingPlan> TrainingPlans
            {
                get { return trainingPlans ?? (trainingPlans = new HashSet<TrainingPlan>()); }
                set { trainingPlans = value; }
            }
        }

        public class TrainingToPerform
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public DateTime DateToPerform { get; set; }

            public virtual TrainingPlan TrainingPlan { get; set; }
            public virtual Workout Workout { get; set; }
        }

        public class Workout
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public virtual Athlete Athlete { get; set; }

            private ICollection<TrainingToPerform> trainingsToPerform;
            public virtual ICollection<TrainingToPerform> TrainingsToPerform
            {
                get { return trainingsToPerform ?? (trainingsToPerform = new HashSet<TrainingToPerform>()); }
                set { trainingsToPerform = value; }
            }
        }

        public class TrainingPlan
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public virtual Athlete Athlete { get; set; }

            private ICollection<TrainingToPerform> trainingsToPerform;
            public virtual ICollection<TrainingToPerform> TrainingsToPerform
            {
                get { return trainingsToPerform ?? (trainingsToPerform = new HashSet<TrainingToPerform>()); }
                set { trainingsToPerform = value; }
            }
        }


        public class Db3 : DbContext
        {
            public Db3()
            {

            }

            public DbSet<Athlete> Athletes { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Workout> Workouts { get; set; }
            public DbSet<TrainingPlan> TrainingPlans { get; set; }
            public DbSet<TrainingToPerform> TrainingsToPerform { get; set; }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

                modelBuilder.Entity<TrainingPlan>()
                    .HasKey(x => x.Id);

                modelBuilder.Entity<Workout>()
                    .HasKey(x => x.Id);

                modelBuilder.Entity<Athlete>()
                    .HasKey(x => x.Id);

                modelBuilder.Entity<Athlete>()
                    .HasMany(a => a.TrainingPlans)
                    .WithRequired(t => t.Athlete)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true)
                    ;

                modelBuilder.Entity<Athlete>()
                    .HasMany(a => a.Workouts)
                    .WithRequired(t => t.Athlete)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true)
                    ;

                modelBuilder.Entity<TrainingToPerform>()
                    .HasKey(x => x.Id);

                modelBuilder.Entity<TrainingToPerform>()
                    .HasRequired(t => t.Workout)
                    .WithOptional()
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false)
                    ;

                modelBuilder.Entity<TrainingToPerform>()
                    .HasRequired(t => t.TrainingPlan)
                    .WithOptional()
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false)
                    ;         
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var db = new Db3();

            var a = new Athlete { Name = "a6"};
            var w = new Workout { Name = "w6", Athlete = a };
            var t = new TrainingPlan { Name = "t6", Athlete = a };
            db.Athletes.Add(a);
            db.Workouts.Add(w);
            db.TrainingPlans.Add(t);
            db.SaveChanges();

            var wtp = new TrainingToPerform { TrainingPlan = t, Workout = w, DateToPerform = DateTime.Now };

            w.TrainingsToPerform.Add(wtp);
            t.TrainingsToPerform.Add(wtp);


            db.TrainingsToPerform.Add(wtp);

            db.SaveChanges();

            Console.WriteLine(db.TrainingsToPerform.First().Workout.Name);

        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Let me try it and I will let you know :D

Comment: I tried your approach but when I see the created table TrainingToPerforms I can't see any reference to the FK of the Workouts and the TrainingPlans... there are no columns to hold those values.

Comment: I left this and now is working correctly:
             modelBuilder.Entity<TrainingPlanWorkouts>()
                .HasRequired(t => t.Workout);




            modelBuilder.Entity<TrainingPlanWorkouts>()
                .HasRequired(t => t.TrainingPlan);

Answer (score 0):

Another thing I can think of is moving all the relations into a new class `ATrainingAthlete` which only brings together the athlete with its workouts and training plans.

```
public class Athlete
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    //public virtual List<Workout> Workouts {get; set;}
    //public virtual List<TrainingPlan> TrainingPlans {get; set;}
}

public class Workout
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    //public virtual Athlete Athlete {get; set;}  //Athlete owner of the WO.
    //public virtual List<TrainingPlan> TrainingPlans {get; set;} //Plans where WO is.
}

public class TrainingPlan
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    //public virtual Athlete Athlete {get; set;}  //Athlete owner of this TP.
    //public virtual List<Workout> Workouts {get; set;} //Workouts in this plan.
}

public class ATrainingAthlete
{
    public int Id {get; set;} 
    // connect the athlete
    public virtual Athlete Athlete {get; set;}
    // with its workouts
    public virtual List<Workout> Workouts {get; set;}
    // and training plans
    public virtual List<TrainingPlan> TrainingPlans {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I will wait for more answers since you mentioned you only know C# and no fluet api / EF. This problem is regarding that.

Comment: Sure. But in many cases a problem can be better solved by changing the model and not simply trying to get it running...